# Multiple Polymer Paper-Listbox in a Page

Tags: listbox, polymer-1.0

I'd like to have a form with multiple Polymer list boxes in it.

```
<paper-listbox selected="0">
<paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
<paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
<paper-item>Item 3</paper-item>
</paper-listbox>

<paper-listbox selected="0">
<paper-item>Item A</paper-item>
<paper-item>Item B</paper-item>
<paper-item>Item C</paper-item>
</paper-listbox>
```

When I do this, I am only able to select one item in both lists. How do I enable selection one from each list?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely would have use same variable in the `selected={{myVariable}}` attribute in both the listboxes. You can use different variables in different listbox `selected={{myVariableOne}}` for the first listbox and `selected={{myVariableTwo}}` for the second listbox.

Checkout the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AR4HGIGPTPWmgwv6M2jF

Comment: Thank you. I mistakenly thought that the selected field is for setting default. From your example, I see that the two lists are indeed independent. I also mistakenly thought otherwise since the highlight appears only on the last selected item from either listbox. Is there a way to keep the highlight on the first listbox if I click on the next?